# Does Google Calendar and its Outlook sync tool support multiple Outlook users?

Tags: google-calendar, outlook

I would like to push Google Calendar events to multiple users who use Outlook. Can this be done if each user installed Google Calendar sync tool and set it up for on way Google -> Outlook?

If events have reminders, even possibly more than one reminder per event, are these reminders pushed to Outlook as well to become Outlook reminders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - I have done this - multiple Outlook users can use Google Calendar Sync to sync to the same Google Calendar.

According to Google's documentation (see heading "Syncing event reminders" [here](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=98565)), some support is provided for syncing reminders.